# Redux Toolkit Query sends empty data to DRF API, ie. request.data is showing empty in django backend views

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, redux-toolkit

I want to send form data using Redux RTK Query to Django API. I have two models User and Profile related with One To One Relationship. Everything works fine in backend as I checked with Postman. I can update in Profile model or Create new entry in Profile model. But when I send my form data from React front end using Redux RTK Query for POST/PATCH, I got request.data as empty **{}** .

**RTK Query:**

```
editProfile: builder.mutation({
  query: (access_token, actualData) => {
    return {
        url:'editprofile/', 
        method:'PATCH', 
        body:actualData, 
        headers:{'authorization' : `Bearer ${access_token}`, 'Content-type':'application/json'}
    }
  }
}),
createProfile: builder.mutation({
  query: (access_token, actualData ) => {
    return {
        url:'createprofile/', 
        method:'POST', 
        body:actualData, 
        headers:{'authorization' : `Bearer ${access_token}`, 'Content-type':'application/json'}
    }
  }
})
```

**view.py** : Through POSTMAN I have checked everything works fine.

```
class UserProfileDataView(APIView):
renderer_classes = [UserRenderer] 
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated] 

def get(self, request, format=None):
    serializer = ProfileSerializer(request.user.profile, context={'request': request})
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

def post(self, request, format=None):
    serializer = ProfileSerializer(data= request.data, context={'request': request})
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()
    return Response ({ 'msg':'Data Updated Successfully'},status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED )

def patch(self, request, format=None):        
    item = Profile.objects.get(user = request.user)
    serializer = ProfileSerializer(item ,data = request.data, partial=True, context={'request': request})
    print(request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    user = serializer.save()
    return Response({'msg':'Profile Updated Successfull', 'locality': user.locality} ,status = status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**print(request.data)** gives **{}**

Why is request.data is showing empty?? I have tried different content-type but nothig works..please help me out!

Comment: Have you tried logging `actualData` in your RTK query? I'd assume the data there is not what you expect

Comment: found my mistake, missed braces in query query: (access_token, actualData) will be query: ({access_token, actualData})